# ¿Cómo consumir un WebService en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, webservice

Estoy tratando de consumir un servicio web desde javascript en Visual ASP.net, los tados txtUsuario, txtPass los obtengo desde un html, el problema que tengo es al momento de armar la petición get der webservice.

Este es el webservice que debo consumir
[image]

Este es mi peticion aramda pero al parecer tengo un problema de sintaxis
[image: !!]

Comment: te aconsejo que escribas el código con el respectivo formato, no utilices imagen para mostrar código.

Comment: o vaya, no lo sabia, muchas gracias por el consejo!